# Strip down everything, except alphanumeric and European characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, alphanumeric, latin1

I am working on validating my commenting script, and I need to strip down all non-alphanumeric chars except those used in Western Europe.

My plan is to regex out all non-alphanumeric characters with:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

But that so far strips out all European characters and a £ sign, so "Café Rouge" becomes "Caf Rouge".

How can I add an array of Euro chars to the above regex.

The array is:

```
£, €, 
á, à, â, ä, æ, ã, å,
è, é, ê, ë,
î, ï, í, ì,
ô, ö, ò, ó, ø, õ,
û, ü, ù, ú,
ÿ,
ñ,
ß
```

I use UTF-8

**SOLUTION:**

```
$comment = preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}\d\s\p{P}]/u', '', $comment);
```

and

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}]/u', '', $name);
```

$name aslo removes punctuation marks and spaces

Thanks for quick replies

Comment: Do you just want to protect against SQL injection? That's a solved problem already. No need to restrict the input for it. - [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Protecting against injection is only one of the issues. I also want a limited amount of non alphanumeric chars, because I might reuse the titles for friendly links later on, and generally, because I don't like weird stuff coming into my DB.

Comment: as someone who writes in non-western scripts and likes to decorate text with useful dingbats on occasion, i kind of resent having my typing called "weird stuff", and i would be really really irritated if a website silently deleted parts of something i wrote.

Comment: Eeevee I know what you mean, but I had to do it in order to have friendly links. For example a user can create a thread that can be accessed at www.example.co.uk/group_name. If a user calls his/her threat "Café", unfortunately the URL will look like this: example.co.uk/caf%3F.Because it is hard to display the letter "é" in most English language URL bars, I ended up regex'ing it into the basic "e".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}\d ]/u', '', $str);
```

Comment: It seems to me that whitespace must also be kept (`/[^\p{Latin}\d\s]/u`).

Comment: @piouPiouM - I am not sure if OP wants tabs and other whitespace character to keep or not. Some European names contains also `'` and `-` characters, so most likely the set of allowed characters will be adjusted by OP based on testing anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9 £€áàâä...]/ui', '', $string);
```

The important part is the `/u` flag. Make sure your source code and `$string` are UTF-8 encoded.

I still think it's the wrong approach, because it severely limits what your users can enter and it *will* annoy some, but whatever floats your boat... BTW, your list contains no punctuation characters.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I want to keep the comments professional, hence 'café' should be café and not cafe; but also I'd rather strip other symbols like hearts, diamonds and such. So I thought an exclusive array would be more suitable than an inclusive one.